# Is there a way to have multiple character's saves on the same map with only one account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to have more then 1 character saved on my map while using only one account?

I only have 1 account but there are 3 of us. We want to alternate playing, but with everyone playing on the same map and having their own stuff (position, inventory, ender chest, mod stuff, etc.).

This is just single player, no server and their will be no more then 1 player playing at a time.

the first answer do not work. I still got all my stuff. I did not start like a new guy and it just seems to reset my mod so now. I lost my progress :( 
good thing I was not fare lol

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't think this is a duplicate in this case, and I'm interested if there is an easy way to do this. That said, the answer to the linked question should still work, just skip step 1, and change the display name every time the player changes.

Comment: Multiple "characters?" Aren't you just talking about one account? Please explain in more detail. Are you saying that you 3 people are sharing one account, going on the same map, and you want everyone to have their own stuff?

Answer (score 1):

There are several files and folders that have to be copied:

- level.dat
- playerdata/
- stats/

If you want to create a user you **copy** those files to a safe location.
If you want to switch users you first have to copy these files to the specific directory and replace them with the files from the folder for the new player.

Comment: would not that just undo all that I build and with the playerdata I try that to take that out but it just makes a new 1 when I load would

Comment: It wouldn't! Those files are only responsible for the items and position (etc.) a player has. The world itself is stored in the ```region``` and ```data``` folders.

Answer (score 0):

You **may** be able to swap out the .dat file located in .\minecraft\world\players for each user.  **BACK UP YOUR WORLD before you attempt this.**  The basic solution would be to move your .dat file into a different location after you close the game and move in the other player's backed up file before they start.  From the server's perspective the player would revert to a previous condition.

This link may be useful when messing with the players folder.  https://minecraft.wiki/w/Server#Reset_player

To set this up...
Start a new world
Player 1:
Login and play
Save and quit
Rename the player .dat file to include your name
Player 2:
(same as player 1)
Player 3:
(same as above)

THEN to switch users...

Player 1:
Rename your .dat file to the original name.
Login and Play
Save and Quit
Rename the player .dat file to include your name
...